# Why does my system freeze during bootup unless I boot into recovery mode?

Tags: linux, boot

I installed some packages, and now when I try to boot into it normally it freezes at this point.
[image]

The only thing I can do from there is reboot the system. When I do that, this is what's displayed.
[image]

The only way to boot into my system is to select "recovery mode," and then when the menu comes up select "continue booting."

What happened to my system? This is Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Is this `oFono` thing the last thing you installed? Check if you configured it properly -- I've had some services before that would simply hang when not configured properly, which is "not so good" in a linear startup process. (BTW, what distro is that? Knowing that, we might be able to give more specific hints on diabling startup services etc.)

Comment: It could also be some half-installed service or such. Go into "rescue" mode, disable that and check (or reinstall, or roll back, or...) this stuff; then try again.

Comment: I am experiencing the same situation with Ubuntu 14.04. In my case it freezes after login without me first booting with (recovery mode) and then doing the "continue normal boot" selection.